# Angularjs -- refresh single column in view after update

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am printing records in view with ng-repeat.

There is a column named status, which is either 0 or 1.

```
<button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="quizStatus(quiz)" ng-if="quiz.status == 0">Publish</button>
<button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="quizStatus(quiz)" ng-if="quiz.status == 1">Drop</button>
```

Depending on the status, if i click the button it will invert status. My controller is sending me 0 or 1 after update.

```
app.controller('quizController', function($scope, $http,$sce){

  $scope.quizStatus = function(quiz) {
    var data = JSON.stringify({id : quiz.id });
     $http.post('./quizStatus', data ).success(function(data) {
          // data = 0 / 1;
          alert("Status Changed");
       });
  };

});
```

I don't want to refresh the whole table as i only need to reflect the status change.

How do i accomplish this?

Comment: What do you mean, refresh the whole table? What do you only want to refresh, and what other things are changing as a result?

Comment: It seems like both button performing same operation only having different text. Correct? In that case I'd use `ng-bind` to change conditional text, but still I'm wondering something is missing.

Comment: If quiz is not the variable you are repeating on, then you can put these buttons outside ng-repeat block

Comment: @FrankerZ its a quiz table. There are other things with status like name, contents, points etc, total 9 columns and lots of rows. The action is performed on status so i want to keep changes to the status column only.

Comment: If you're not updating any of the other view variables, nothing else should change...

Comment: @PankajParkar yeah only text is changing in the button. I tried a scope variable and in the controller after update i assigned text according to the result. But when i refresh the page the initial scope variable value is printed in every button.

Comment: @FrankerZ answer me this. I get 0 or 1 every time i click on status button. how do i reflect these results in my button without touching anything else.

Comment: Can you post the code for your controller?

Comment: @mcgraphix check code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just update the status of the quiz when you get the data back:

```
$scope.quizStatus = function(quiz) {
var data = JSON.stringify({id : quiz.id });
 $http.post('./quizStatus', data ).success(function(data) {
      // data = 0 / 1;
      alert("Status Changed");
      quiz.status = data;
   });
};
```